# Does Banshee have a log of files deleted from the drive from within Banshee?

Tags: 10.04, banshee, files, delete

does Banshee have a log of files deleted from the drive from within Banshee? Apparently all these dupes I was seeing in my library and deleting weren't dupes, but a bug :(

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=632465

So I have a lot of missing files and want to know which ones are missing/I've recently deleted from within Banshee to see if I can somehow recover them, as I have no way of knowing this now other than by trying to play the fly and Banshee falling silent and skipping it. It's still listed though, since Banshee still has it its imported files db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an answer to your main question, but it could solve your problem: Open `Banshee` and in the menu `Tools` run `Rescan Music Library`.

[image: banshee menu rescan music]

This should work, as long you didn't delete the files from your harddisk.